# Grepping particular pattern using sed command

Tags: bash

I have one file (Let say a.txt) whose contents is as shown below. I want to grep only errors name only before colon (:) like DK2.a.Iq_abc_vu, LAP.ABCD.1 but not grep "11xAB2_B_1" error as violation value is 0 except there is one special case mentioned at last of the question. We have to grep only those errors whose value is non zero (like DK2.a.Iq_abc_vu,LAP.ABCD.1 but not 11xAB2_B_1 as it value is showing 0 violations). The format of a.txt file is remain same across different files also. Here there is one special case when "violation" word is coming in that case we have grep "text_abcd" and "text_jkl" as error not "violation". Can you please help me how can grep I these errors as shown in below output.

```
$ cat a.txt file
DK2.a.Iq_abc_vu : To avoid > 500 um x 500.0 um Metal empty space after IP abutment empty space must on IP boundary corner  
interacting ........................................ 1 violation found.                                                                                      
interacting ........................................ 1 violation found.

DM3.a.7.abc_vu : To avoid > 100.0 um x 100.0 um Metal empty space after TV boundary corner  having some thing    
interacting ........................................ 2 violations found.

LAP.ABCD.1 : Voltage high this is one type of error coming some thing violations. This error can be removed by providing spacing    
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 1 violation found.                                                                                 
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 1 violation found.   
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 10 violation found.  
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 1 violation found.

11xAB2_B_1 : 10xAB area >= 100um2  
not_inside ......................................... 0 violations found.

Violation  
text_abcd:text_pqrs .......................... 2 violations found.    
text_jkl:jkl_jkl ............................. 2 violations found.
```

Desired output:

```
DK2.a.Iq_abc_vu   
DM3.a.7.abc_vu  
LAP.ABCD.1  
text_abcd  
text_jkl
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: I had use the following commands.

Comment: sed 's/ \+/ /g' a.txt | sed 's/\(violations found.\)/\1\n/g' | sed 's/\(violation found.\) \([A-Z]\|[0-9]\)/\1\n \2/g' | sed 's/ : . * \.\.\+\(.*\)/ : \1/' | grep -v "\.\.\+ 0 violations found\|layout_drawn_errors\|FLAG\|off_grid_xy\|vertex\|Not executed" | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: Output is coming like this-

Comment: DK2.a.Iq_abc_vu
interacting
interacting

DM3.a.7.abc_vu
interacting


LAP.ABCD.1
net_abcd:net_abcd
net_abcd:net_abcd
net_abcd:net_abcd
net_abcd:net_abcd

11xAB2_B_1


Violation
text_abcd:text_pqrs

text_jkl:jkl_jkl

Comment: I do not want "interacting" , "net_abcd:net_abcd" and "Violation" as output. What filter should I set so that these will not print in output. I want to print only the errors shown in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer doesn't have to be based on `sed` ...

We can use `egrep` to keep only those lines that meet one of the following criteria:

- line contains a colon with leading/trailing space (`:`) or the word `violation` (case insensitive)
- from the resulting lines we then discard lines that contain `0 violations`

At this point we have:

```
$ egrep -i " : |violation" a.txt | egrep -v " 0 violations"
DK2.a.Iq_abc_vu : To avoid > 500 um x 500.0 um Metal empty space after IP abutment empty space must on IP boundary corner
interacting ........................................ 1 violation found.
interacting ........................................ 1 violation found.
DM3.a.7.abc_vu : To avoid > 100.0 um x 100.0 um Metal empty space after TV boundary corner  having some thing
interacting ........................................ 2 violations found.
LAP.ABCD.1 : Voltage high this is one type of error coming some thing violations. This error can be removed by providing spacing
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 1 violation found.
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 1 violation found.
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 10 violation found.
net_abcd:net_abcd .............................. 1 violation found.
11xAB2_B_1 : 10xAB area >= 100um2
Violation
text_abcd:text_pqrs .......................... 2 violations found.
text_jkl:jkl_jkl ............................. 2 violations found.
```

Now we can use `awk` to keep track of 2 types of errors:

- (1) line contains `[space]:[space]`, so we store the error name and if the next line contains the string `violation` we print the error name and then clear the error name (to keep from printing it twice)
- (2) line starts with `^Violation` in which case we'll obtain/print the error name from each follow-on line that contains the string `violation` (error name is the portion of the line before the `:`)

The `awk` code to implement this looks like:

```
awk '
/ : /        { errname = $1 ; next }
/^Violation/ { errname = $1 ; next }
/violation/  { if ( errname == "Violation" ) { split($1,a,":") ; print a[1] ; next }
               if ( errname != "" )          { print errname   ; errname="" ; next }
             }
'
```

Pulling the `egrep` and `awk` snippets together gives us:

```
$ egrep -i " : |violation" a.txt | egrep -v " 0 violations" | awk '
/ : /        { errname = $1 ; next }
/^Violation/ { errname = $1 ; next }
/violation/  { if ( errname == "Violation" ) { split($1,a,":") ; print a[1] ; next }
               if ( errname != "" )          { print errname   ; errname="" ; next }
             }
'
```

With the following results:

```
DK2.a.Iq_abc_vu
DM3.a.7.abc_vu
LAP.ABCD.1
text_abcd
text_jkl
```

Comment: Thanks!!  In addition to the above text file I have violation name that is not separated by colon (:) rather there is space in that case how can we grep that violations also?

Comment: DM3.a.7.abc_vu                                                                                                                                                                                                                           To avoid > 100.0 um x 100.0 um Metal empty space after TV boundary corner  having some thing    
interacting ........................................ 2 violations found.

Comment: In the above, I have to grep "DM3.a.7.abc_vu" violation only. So what changes needs to be done in the above solution  that you shared?

Comment: We have the violations name either before colon (:) or before space now

Comment: Can you please help me?